# Ebean: @OneToMany to the same Entity

Tags: java, sql, jpa, playframework, one-to-many

I have the following scenario where a User can make a Reservation on a Campaign.

Eg. User wants to reserve a Campaign(eg 20% off on a book). I want the reservation table to look like this: |id|user_id|campaign_id|

User can make many reservations.
Campaign can be reserved by many users.
Reservation will contain what user reserved what campaign.

User.java

```
@Entity
public class User extends Model {
    @Id
    public Long id;
    public String username;
    public String password;
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
    public List<Reservation> reservations;
}
```

Campaign.java

```
@Entity
public class Campaign extends Model {
    @Id
    public Long id;
    public String name;
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
    public List<Reservation> reservations;
}
```

Reservations.java

```
@Entity
public class Reservation extends Model {
    @Id
    public Long id;
}
```

How come this doesn't work?

EDIT:
I get a reservation table that has an id and an user_id, but no campaign_id

Comment: can you post the log? maybe it is because there is no campaign_id in your table reservation, and another thing as it stand a user could make N reservation for the same campaign like this, user:A campaign: B, user A make a reservation to campaign B, 1|A|B, if he try to make another reservation on the same campaign after exactly 1 second he could do it and it will goes to the DB as n|A|B, is this behaviour ok with your Scenario? i know is set to oneToMany but... just to make you think about it.

Answer (score 0):

You may consider doing it like this,

User.java

```
@Entity
public class User extends Model {
    @Id
    public Long id;
    public String username;
    public String password;
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST,mappedBy="user")
    public List<Reservation> reservations;
}
```

Campaign.java

```
@Entity
public class Campaign extends Model {
    @Id
    public Long id;
    public String name;
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST,mappedBy="campaign")
    public List<Reservation> reservations;
}
```

Reservation.java

```
@Entity
public class Reservation extends Model {
    @Id
    public Long id;
    @ManyToOne
    public User user;
    @ManyToOne
    public Campaign campaign;
}
```